# Profile the locks in OpenJDK or any Java VM

Tags: concurrency, jvm, java, jrockit

The thing I want to do is, count how many locks happened during the execution of one JVM application. (I know the lock number may change from run to run, but I just want to get the average number). And I cannot change the application, since it is one benchmark.

I have tried to use JRockit-JDK, but two problems:

1. -Djrockit.lockprofiling=true does not give me the profile information ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/locktuning.html#wp1089816));
2. does "-Xverbose:locks" print the right information?

The platform I am using is Ubuntu Server.
Any suggestions on this would be great appreciated.

Comment: In case anyone want to know the solution, I hacked the kernel to profile the lock contention at kernel level. It may include the noise from system, but so far it is the best way I got.

Answer (score 0):

To do this previously I've used AspectJ with a pointcut that detects locking and a counter i.e.

```
public aspect CountLocks{

   private static AtomicInteger locks = new AtomicInteger();

   before(Object l) : lock() && args(l) { locks.incrementAndGet(); }

   after() : execution(void main(String[])) { System.out.println(locks+" locks"); }

}
```

But this obviously involves weaving the code, potentially changing its performance characteristics.

Comment: Thanks first. I am running with benchmarks, so codes should not be changed.